# How to declare and assign values to key value pairs in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I declared and and assigning values to an array in the following way but it says error at this line  attributes.categoryKey: '2051' unexpected token '.'.Can someone help me.Thanks.

```
  var arr2 = [ {'attributes': {'categoryKey': '' },'value': '' } ]
         $.each(value, function (i, v) {
         arr2.push({ attributes.categoryKey: '2051', 'value': v.name });
```

Comment: [Computed object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) take the form `[variable]`, so it would be `{ [variable]:"value" }`

Comment: can you edit my code pls.....

Comment: What is value on which you are iterating?

Comment: value is an array of object having values with name and its working fine

Comment: please post the data for value as well, without the context, it is not possible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly

```
 arr2.push({ attributes.categoryKey: '2051', 'value': v.name });
```

as here attributes is not defined yet so .categoryKey is invalid hence you need to define its as further properties of object as you did initially

It needs to be as :

```
 var arr2 = [ {'attributes': {'categoryKey': '' },'value': '' } ]
 var value = [{name:"name1"}]       
 $.each(value, function (i, v) {
     arr2.push({ attributes: {categoryKey: '2051'}, 'value': v.name });
 })
 console.log(arr2);
```

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ggcjjh7/

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong syntax:

var object = {key: 'value'};

the key must be clearly and we cannot use some expression in it.

But I have a suggestion to by pass this:

```
var a = {'value': v.name };
a[attributes.categoryKey] = '2051';
```

Finally:

```
arr2.push(a);
```